# Convert a c# Delegate to use Lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

Can you convert the following delegate to use a lambda expression ?

```
public Action<int, Func<int, int>> DisplayResult = delegate (int result, Func<int, int> function)
{
       Console.WriteLine(function(result));
};
```

I've tried removing all the data types etc but its not working out

Comment: I know its not a coding service but this is my last resort.  I have to refactor the above code to use a Lambda expression. To use a Lambda I need to remove all references to variables like ints, Func and the delegate too. something like = (result, operation) =>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Action<int, Func<int, int>> DisplayResult = (result, function) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(function(result));
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much vyrp.  This is absolutely perfect.  You know I spent 2 hours on this but you would never believe me

Comment: @Aindriu If it answers the question, could you accept the answer?

Comment: Yes ! just waiting 4 minutes